# NameError for variable that I won't have value for until runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary for creating insert statements for a test I'm doing.  The insert value for the description field needs to have the id of the current row, WHICH I DO NOT HAVE until I run the program.  Also, that ID increments by 1 each time I insert, and the description for each insert has to have its corresponding row_num.

I want to load a dictionary of all the fields in the table in advance, so I can use the information in it to create the insert and alter statements for my test.  I don't want to hardcode the test_value of a field in the code; I want what's supposed to be in it to be defined in the dictionary, and calculated at runtime. The dictionary is meant to be a template for what I want the value of the field to be.

I am getting the max id from the database, and adding 1 to it.  That's the row number.  I want the value that's being inserted for the description to be, for example, `Row Num: {row_num} - Num Inserts {num_inserts} - Wait Time {wait_time}`.  I have the num_inserts and the wait_time from a config file.  They are defined in advance.

I am getting `NameError: name 'row_num' is not defined` no matter how I've tried to define row_num in this dictionary.  When I import the dictionary, the row_num isn't available yet, hence the error.

Here's a small snippet of my database fields dictionary (users is the table in this example):

```
all_fields_dict = {
    'users':
       {
        'first_name': {
            'db_field' : 'FirstName',
            'datatype': 'varchar(50)',
            'test_value': {utils.calc_field_value(['zfill', 'FirstName'])}, # another attempt that didn't work
            'num_bool': False
        },
        'username': {
            'db_field' : 'username',
            'datatype': 'varchar(50)',
            'test_value': f"user{utils.get_random_str(5)}", # this works, but it's a diff kind of calculation
            'num_bool': False,
        },
        'description': {
            'db_field' : 'description',
            'datatype': 'text',
            'test_value': f"{utils.get_desc_info(row_num)}", # one of my attempts - fails
            'num_bool': False,
        },
   }
}
```

Among other things, I have tried:

1. `{row_num}`:

   ```
   test_value: f"{row_num"}
   ```
2. calling a function that returns the row num:

   ```
   def get_row_num()
       return row_num

   test_value: f"{utils.get_row_num()}
   ```
3. calling a function that CALLS the get_row_num function:

   ```
   def get_desc_info():
       row_num = get_row_num()
       return f"Row Num: {row_num} - Wait Time: {wait_time} - Total Inserts: {num_inserts}"

   test_value: f"{utils.get_desc_info()}"
   ```
4. I've even tried creating a function with a switcher that returns the get_row_num function, if 'rnum' is passed in as the test_value

   ```
   def calc_field_value(type):

       switcher = {
               'rnum': get_row_num(),
               etc
       }
       return switcher[type]

   test_value: f"{utils.calc_field_value('rnum')
   ```
5. I've tried declaring it as global in just about every place I can think of.
6. I haven't tried eval, because of all the security warnings I've read about it.

Same thing, every single time.

Comment: The values for `f` strings have to be available when they're defined, if you need to defer that put the definition of the dictionary inside a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `test_field` to some placeholder value, or simply don't set a value at all.

Then, later in the code when you do know the value, update the dict.

Comment: This is ultimately what I did, using delimiters to pass extra information and then parsing the value to create the output I wanted.